# Restrict Search Scope with Search Widget/Geocoder

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I've implemented an autocomplete searchbox on the map via the Geocoder. It's working fine. However, I would want to limit the returned results via the Geocoder to city limits.

> For example: When a user types in "305 Quincy St", I want it to search for this address only within a city, let's say Florida.

At present, it is looking for this address from all around the world.

1. Can this be done?
2. Is it possible to make the autocomplete widget search within a
   boundary extent on the map?

The closest I've come across is using the `sourceCountry` option of the Geocoder options and set it to USA. But it would be awesome if there was a way to have a `sourceCity` too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a searchExtent parameter that can be used like this:

searchExtent=-104,35.6,-94.32,41

[More info about searchExtent parameter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r30000001p000000#ESRI_SECTION3_754130F61997429E9B6BFFF4A118DF98)

Comment: So I can pass it as an argument to the geocoder function?

Comment: Yes, and if your map is using a different wkid than the geocoder does you must also specify it.